# how to change joi.array schema error message

Tags: typescript, schema, joi

i have this schema:

```
export const orderSchema = Joi.object({
  productsIds: Joi.array().items(Joi.number()).min(1).required().message,
});
```

and this middleware:

```
const orderValidation = (req: Request, _res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const { body } = req;
  const { error } = orderSchema.validate(body);
  if (error) {    
    throw new ThrowError(
      error.message
        .includes('required') ? statusCodes.BAD_REQUEST : statusCodes.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
      error.message, 
    );
  }

  next();
};

export default orderValidation;
```

in my error message i get: ""value" must contain at least 1 items"

and i need a way to change this message to :  ""productsIds" must include only numbers"

Answer (score 0):

Joi has a `messages` method that lets you pass in particular messages to use for particular validation failures:

```js
const productIdsSchema = Joi.array().items(Joi.number()).min(1).required().messages({
  "any.required": "productsIds must include only numbers",
  "number.base": "productsIds must include only numbers"
});
export const orderSchema = Joi.object({
  productsIds: productIdsSchema,
});
```